# Can I remove category name from GCMBroadcastReceiver or is there any alternative name to be given instead of package name

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

In my application, I have to implement GCM Push Notification.In the manifest file the receiver will be as follows:

```
<receiver  android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"             
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>                
<!-- Receives the actual messages. -->   
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />                 
<!-- Receives the registration id. -->                 
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />              
<category android:name="com.companyname.project" />             
</intent-filter>         
</receiver>
```

I want to remove the package name from the category name. Is it possible or is there any alternative value that can be given as category name.

Comment: can you tell why you want to do it?

Comment: I want to remove the package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

category name should be there. It is used to filter the GCM messages. The point of the  is to filter incoming GCM notifications based on your app / package name.

The docs for GCM show  and as you have to register specific apps to allow GCM, this makes sense.

If you think about it, there may be any number of apps on an Android device which are registered for GCM. The fact they will all be receiving messages using the same core software means there has to be some way to 'route' the messages to the correct app - if there wasn't a way to do this, all GCM-registered apps would receive each others' messages.

Comment: Actually my requirement was to remove the usage of package names. Is there any alternative for using package name as categoryname

Comment: @Julie No. You have to use it.